# Filtering collisions in Chipmunk for trapped bodies

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone, chipmunk, simpleaudioengine

**Background**

- I'm making an iOS app for kids where you can use your finger to drag balls around on a screen.
- I'm using Chipmunk 7.0.0 for the physics simulation.
- I've adapted the [Chipmunk demo code](https://github.com/slembcke/Chipmunk2D/blob/master/Demo/ChipmunkDemo.c) to implement the dragging functionality.
- I'm using 2 ms fixed time step. (It's not like my app has anything better to do...)

**Issue**

I've recently added code to play a sound whenever the balls collide with each other or with a wall, which I'm doing inside a `postSolve` callback:

```c
static void postSolve(cpArbiter *arb, cpSpace *space, cpDataPointer userData)
{
    GameLayer *layer = (__bridge GameLayer *)userData;
    [layer collisionHandler:arb];
}

-(void) collisionHandler:(cpArbiter*)arb
{
    if(cpArbiterIsFirstContact(arb)) {
        [[SimpleAudioEngine sharedEngine] playEffect:kCollisionEffectFilename];
    }
}
```

Here's the problem... When I drag a ball into a wall, it generates a very large number of collisions, even when filtering on `cpArbiterIsFirstContact`, and it sounds terrible. It appears that the ball is bouncing off the wall, being driven back into wall by the constraint, rinse, and repeat. I'd like to play the collision sound only once or twice in this scenario.

**Things I've tried that don't seem to work...**

- Filtering using `cpArbiterTotalKE`, `cpArbiterTotalImpulse`, or relative velocity: Impulse, kinetic energy, and relative velocity are all in the range of typical collisions.
- Using a `separate` callback: The ball really is bouncing off the wall multiple times.
- Reducing the step size: The physics engine actually takes longer to converge.
- Rate limiting the sound effects: Better, but the ball still makes noise even after it looks like it's stationary.

**Question**

Is there a way to filter collisions for trapped bodies?

Comment: doesn't chipmunk provide a callback for the very first contact event of two contacting bodies?

Comment: @LearnCocos2D Yes, there's the `begin` callback, but it has the same problem as the `separate` callback. Here's the sequence: 1) Ball collides with wall. 2) Collision imparts an impulse to the ball causing it to bounce off. 3) Ball and wall separate. 4) Constraint solver provides a force driving the ball back into the wall, causing another collision and returning to step 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple and effective solution is to avoid playing the sound in quick succession.

When the ball contacts with the wall, check if the ball's "last contact" timer is lower than the current time. If so, play the sound and set the ball's "last contact" time to the current time plus x, where x is the timeout duration the sound shouldn't play again (ie 0.5 seconds).

In cocos2d-iphone you can add up an update method's deltaTime to keep track of time. There are also a number of ways to get system time, for example `[NSDate date].timeIntervalSince1970` gives you the current number of seconds since 1970. I know, seems ridiculous, but if you get that number again sometime later, and subtract the previous number of seconds you get the difference in seconds, that's all that counts.

Comment: Simple solutions are great. :-) That makes perfect sense to disable sounds on a per-ball basis instead of globally across the app (which was just sounding strange). Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

So you are using a constraint to drag the ball around, and the ball is elastic correct? Have you tried tweaking the constraint parameters at all? If the constraint has a lower maxForce, the chance for oscillations would drop significantly.

Another thing that can help is to increase the space's collision slop (how much shapes are allowed to overlap). The default value is 0.1 (in whatever scale you are using), but increasing it to a pixel or so can help this sort of thing significantly without being very visible.

Comment: Thank you... Those are all good ideas as well. I'll try playing with the constraint's maxForce and the collision slop.